# AttributeError("Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Symbols.symbol has an attribute 'split'")

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to select rows from an sql table which contains *stock symbols* along with related data.

However some of the rows in the table have symbols in the following format `{symbol}.{exchange} for example,` AAPL.NQ`.

I am trying to look up all rows that would match a particular stock symbol 'ZYX' irrespective of of the trailing exchange. So for the belong example, `symbol_ = 'ZYX'` all rows that contain the symbol `ZYX`, `ZYX.AB',` ZYX.DB' would be fetched.

```py
symbol_ = 'ZYX'
currency_ = 'USD'
security_type_ = 'etf'

matching_pi = session.execute(select(Symbols).where(Symbols.symbol.split('.')[0] == symbol_)).scalars().all()
```

Adding the `.split('.')[0] is resulting in the following error which is expected.` AttributeError("Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Symbols.symbol has an attribute 'split'")`

I would like to disregard the part of the symbol string that comes after the `.` in a symbol name. `ABC.XZ` should be interpreted as `ABC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use [startswith](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.startswith).

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql import or_

symbol_ = 'ZYX'
currency_ = 'USD'
security_type_ = 'etf'

matching_pi = session.execute(select(Symbols).where(or_(Symbols.symbol == symbol_, Symbols.symbol.startswith(symbol_ + ".")))
```

## Full Example

```py
import sys
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Integer,
    String,
)
from sqlalchemy.schema import (
    Column,
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.sql import select, or_, func


username, password, db = sys.argv[1:4]


engine = create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{username}:{password}@/{db}", echo=True)


Base = declarative_base()

class Symbol(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'symbols'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    symbol = Column(String)


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)



with Session(engine) as session:
    # Insert valid and invalid symbols.
    valid_labels = ["abc", "abc.def"]
    invalid_labels = ["abcx", "abcx.def", "ab.c"]
    session.add_all([Symbol(symbol=s) for s in valid_labels] + [Symbol(symbol=s) for s in invalid_labels])
    session.commit()

with Session(engine) as session:
    # Make sure all symbols were inserted.
    stmt = select(Symbol)
    symbols = session.execute(stmt).scalars().all()
    assert len(symbols) == len(valid_labels + invalid_labels)

def test_labels(found_labels):
    # Make sure the found labels are the valid ones.
    assert len(found_labels) == len(valid_labels)
    for label in valid_labels:
        assert label in found_labels
    for label in invalid_labels:
        assert label not in found_labels


with Session(engine) as session:
    # Lookup symbols matching our test symbol with split_part
    symbol = 'abc'
    stmt = select(Symbol).where(func.split_part(Symbol.symbol, ".", 1) == symbol)
    symbols = session.execute(stmt).scalars().all()
    found_labels = [s.symbol for s in symbols]

    test_labels(found_labels)

with Session(engine) as session:
    # Lookup symbols matching our test symbol with or(equals,startswith)
    symbol = 'abc'
    stmt = select(Symbol).where(or_(Symbol.symbol == symbol, Symbol.symbol.startswith(symbol + ".")))
    symbols = session.execute(stmt).scalars().all()
    found_labels = [s.symbol for s in symbols]

    test_labels(found_labels)
```

Comment: i will try this solution. However i executed a raw sql statement using https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-string-functions/postgresql-split_part/ and it solved the problem. It is not ideal as it does not use SQLAlchemy syntax. Thank you. @ian-wilson

Comment: I added split_part example too.